# Infectious disease in Tanzanian lowlands

Tags: infectious-diseases, geography, lumbago-low-back-pain, malaria, altitude-topography

people moving from the Tanzanian highlands, e.g. Usambara mountains, Kilimandjaro region, to the plains are quite often affected by a disease with the following symptoms:

- onset similar to malaria, but appetite not diminished
- no joint pain, but severe back pain reaching from neck to hip
- severe symptoms for about 1 week, weakness and coughs remain for much longer
- with rest and good nourishment people recover within weeks to months, otherwise may be fatal
- inhabitants of the plains are not affected

Does anybody have information about this disease?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Rift Valley fever](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs207/en/)?